# Xamarin set element weight in c#

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin

I am working on a new Xamarin based project. I have to manage element count on the activity dynamically in the code, however I have an issue with setting weight of elements. As an example of layout I'd like to have:

[image: activity]

The first row is made in xaml as an example. Other lines are the result I get adding new items through the code, although the markup I create in the c# code is equal to xaml rows markup.

Here is the c# code:

```
LinearLayout contentView = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.ATMListContentLayout);

foreach (var item in BitcoinQueryInfo.ATMList.OrderBy(x => x.id))
{
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this)
            {
                WeightSum = 100,
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            };
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsRow = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    row.LayoutParameters = paramsRow;

    TextView text = new TextView(this)
            {
                Text = item.id + " " + item.address,
                TextSize = 20,
            };
    text.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsText = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    paramsText.Weight = 70;
    text.LayoutParameters = paramsText;

    Button button = new Button(this)
            {
                Text = "Sell BTC",
                TextSize = 20
            };
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsBtn = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
    paramsBtn.Weight = 30;
    text.LayoutParameters = paramsBtn;

    button.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.orange);
    button.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#000000"));

    row.AddView(text);
    row.AddView(button);
    contentView.AddView(row);

    button.Click += delegate
             {
                 BitcoinQueryInfo.selectedATMId = item.id;
                 var newInstance = new Intent(this, typeof(BTCAmountScreen));
                 StartActivity(newInstance);
             };
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I set the weight of elements for each row I add in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WeightSum` and `Weight` are a `float` value.

You have to choices:

**1.** Remove the `WeightSum = 100`.

From de [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum):

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

---

**2.** Make `WeightSum = 1.0f`, `paramsText.Weight = 0.7f;` and `paramsBtn.Weight = 0.3f;`